# PHPMyadmin no muestra los ultimos registros de la tabla incluso agregando un índice

Tags: phpmyadmin

He visto esta misma consulta en otra pregunta y la solución que reportó quien tuvo este mismo problema fue que agregó la característica de "índice" a la clave primaria que es un autoicremental, sin embargo he realizado esta acción y mi problema persiste.

A continuación el detalle de mi problema:

Tengo una tabla logs que tiene 92,212 registros. Cuando voy la pestaña "Examinar" en phpmyadmin para ver los registros de la tabla, doy click en el símbolo ">>" para ir a la "ultima pagina", básicamente para ir al final de la tabla y ver los registros mas recientes.

Phpmyadmin no muestra los últimos registros, siempre se queda en el registros de hace un mes y me dice que no hay nada mas después del ultimo registro que me muestra (83500), pero si manualmente hago un SELECT * FROM logs WHERE ID > 80000;, la consulta si me muestra los últimos registros.

La tabla maneja su campo ID Auto incremental, por lo tanto los registros mas nuevos si tienen los números mas grandes.

Como puedo resolver esto? Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: La solución a tu problema depende enteramente del uso de phpmyadmin? Lo digo por qué si a nivel de código funciona no veo el problema

Comment: Tu vista esta ordenada de alguna forma? Ninguna base de datos asegura como se van a mostrar los registros, a menos que los ordenes. PHPmyadmin es solo un gestor de tu base de datos. No tiene nada que ver con los datos o como mostrarlos.

Comment: Localmente puedo instalar una aplicación de escritorio para acceder a los datos, sin embargo es muy útil acceder vía web para ver los registros de la bdd. Es así que he considerado colocar el tag de phpmyadmin para la pregunta. Agradezco su interés en ayudar.

Comment: phpmyadmin siempre me muestra en orden del autoincremental por defecto. Adicional hice la prueba de correr SELECT * FROM `logs` order by id_logs, sin embargo el problema persiste. Debo mencionar que cuando estoy en la pantalla que muestra las tablas de la bdd, ahí indica la cantidad total de registros que efectivamente son 92,212 y no 83,500 que me muestra la consulta. Como lo he mencionado, si hago  SELECT * FROM logs WHERE id_logs > 80000, me aparecen sin problema los registros faltantes.

Comment: Voy a añadir un nuevo detalle, phpmyadmin incrementa la cantidad de líneas de registros visibles más o menos en 10k conforme se siguen incrementando registros en la base de datos, sin embargo no muestra hasta la última línea como se había reportado.